# How to convert raw 264 file to MP4 provided by Luowice IP camera?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, conversion, h.264, ip-camera

I recently bought an IP camera by Luowice, model [LWS-R8-2MP](http://www.luowice.com/en/R8-download.html). The camera provides a function where a video is uploaded to a FTP server when motion is detected. The camera uploads `.264` files. My plan is to trigger a script once a file is uploaded which converts the file to `.mp4` and delivers it via an instant messaging service. However I'm unable to convert the file as it seems to be either an uncommon or proprietary format. I've tried the solution mentioned [here](https://askubuntu.com/questions/690015/how-can-i-convert-264-file-to-mp4) but when I run

```
ffmpeg -framerate 24 -i A180126_222057_222111.264 -c copy output.mp4
```

I receive the following error output (this is on macOS however the target system is Linux):

```
ffmpeg version 3.4.1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.39.2)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/3.4.1 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags= --host-ldflags= --enable-gpl --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libx264 --enable-libxvid --enable-opencl --enable-videotoolbox --disable-lzma
  libavutil      55. 78.100 / 55. 78.100
  libavcodec     57.107.100 / 57.107.100
  libavformat    57. 83.100 / 57. 83.100
  libavdevice    57. 10.100 / 57. 10.100
  libavfilter     6.107.100 /  6.107.100
  libavresample   3.  7.  0 /  3.  7.  0
  libswscale      4.  8.100 /  4.  8.100
  libswresample   2.  9.100 /  2.  9.100
  libpostproc    54.  7.100 / 54.  7.100
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] SEI type 128 size 576 truncated at 128
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] SEI type 128 size 576 truncated at 95
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] SEI type 128 size 576 truncated at 128
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] SEI type 128 size 576 truncated at 95
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] SEI type 128 size 576 truncated at 128
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] SEI type 128 size 576 truncated at 95
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] non-existing PPS 0 referenced
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] decode_slice_header error
[h264 @ 0x7f8678801200] no frame!
[h264 @ 0x7f8677004200] decoding for stream 0 failed
[h264 @ 0x7f8677004200] Could not find codec parameters for stream 0 (Video: h264 (Main), none(progressive)): unspecified size
Consider increasing the value for the 'analyzeduration' and 'probesize' options
Input #0, h264, from 'A180126_222057_222111.264':
  Duration: N/A, bitrate: N/A
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (Main), none(progressive), 24 fps, 24 tbr, 1200k tbn, 48 tbc
[mp4 @ 0x7f867608aa00] dimensions not set
Could not write header for output file #0 (incorrect codec parameters ?): Invalid argument
Stream mapping:
  Stream #0:0 -> #0:0 (copy)
    Last message repeated 1 times
```

I've contacted the Luowice support but they only provide a Windows application on their [download site](http://www.luowice.com/en/R8-download.html) for converting the files. Also they didn't explain what's so special about their file format. I'm looking for a solution which works on Linux.

Has anyone managed to convert `.264` files provided by this camera model? A sample file can be downloaded [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1MiJP2tA2_yO7pDCeBlXJP5jFysUS2Krw/view?usp=sharing).

**Update:**

I've contact the support of Luowice and they say that the `.264` files have been additionally "compressed" for saving storage space on the SD card of the camera. Unfortunately they can't explain how they compress the files due to "corporate policy".

**Update 2:**

I compiled the C application of the [article](https://www.spitzner.org/kkmoon.html) mentioned by Alain.fr and let it run over the sample file. It outputs an `.mp4` file. Unfortunately this file still cannot be played by VLC **but** when I run

```
ffmpeg -framerate 25 -i A180126_222057_222111.mp4 -c copy output.mp4
```

on the file produced by the converter application finally a playable video is produced :)

**Conclusion:**

Instead of an additional compression as claimed by Luowice actually some garbage is added to the H.264 stream which needs to be stripped.

**Update 3:**

Based on the converter application by [Ralph Spitzner](https://www.spitzner.org/kkmoon.html), which is written in C, I've created a [Node.js port](https://github.com/svenjacobs/chipcaco) since my application is written in Node.js ;)

Comment: Did you try to see the `.264` file with vlc? If it works you can use vlc itself, or at least you may have some information more.

Comment: Based on that output, this is not regular .264 files. You will need to pre-parse to remove whatever proprietary stuff is being added.

Comment: Can you provide a short sample file?

Comment: @Hastur Tried with VLC and it doesn't play the file.

Comment: @LordNeckbeard I've added a link to a sample file. Please see above.

Comment: Even if it doesn't start with `vlc`, it is reported  as `H264 - MPEG-4 AVC (part 10) (h264)` at `1920x1080`. No digital fingerprint found. Just in case it should result useful for further attempts...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found an explaination on the proprietary format [here](https://www.spitzner.org/kkmoon.html) with a small soft to convert to mp4. If it can help

Comment: That looks interesting! Thanks for this find!

Comment: That did it! Please see my updated post. Thank you very much!